# How to retrieve all keys from hashtable containing "Keys" and "Values" text?

Tags: powershell, syntax, properties, key, hashtable

In PowerShell you can get all keys from a `Hashtable` using the `Keys` property:

```
$ht=@{
    "1"="10";
    "2"="20";
}
$ht.Keys
```

This returns:

```
2
1
```

BUT this:

```
$ht=@{
    "Keys"="Keys text";
    "text1"="text1111"
}
$ht.Keys
```

will return `Keys text` (the value of the `Keys` item)

Is there any way to force `.Keys` to return the `Keys` property instead the `Keys` item's value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a bug since the syntax to retrieve the `Keys` entry is superseding the `HashTable`'s `Keys` property, though I could see one expecting it to behave either way.  According to the [Adding a key of 'keys' to a Hashtable breaks access to the .Keys property](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3176) issue on GitHub, this *is* a bug but would require a breaking change to correct, so the workaround below was added to the documentation.

According to [`about_Hash_Tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables#displaying-hash-tables):

> If the key name collides with one of the property names of the HashTable type, you can use `PSBase` to access those properties. For example, if the key name is `keys` and you want to return the collection of Keys, use this syntax:
>
> `$hashtable.PSBase.Keys`

You could also retrieve the property value through reflection...

```
PS> $ht.GetType().GetProperty('Keys').GetValue($ht)
text1
Keys
```

Comment: Thanks.I had some weird results from something like ($ht.Keys.GetEnumerator()|Select-Object -Unique) -join,";". and it was like What! Where does this come from?.Turns out this creepy stuff

Comment: My first attempt was to use `.GetEnumerator()`, too, but that ends up enumerating the `String` value of the `Keys` item and not the `Keys` property.

Comment: Ah, @Nas got it.  You need to call `GetEnumerator()` on `$ht`, not `$ht.Keys`.  So close.

Comment: Probably a bug. It should be: $ht.Values return Values property and $ht."Values" return item value.

Comment: I found a PowerShell GitHub issue referencing this behavior and a workaround, which I have added to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ht | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Keys
```

Comment: Also a possibility `$ht.GetEnumerator().Name`

Comment: Thanks. It seems that there is no way to force it. Something like {I want my Keys/Values} $ ht.Values

Comment: Note that the `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` only works in _Windows PowerShell_. In PowerShell _Core_, `@{ foo = 'bar'; Keys = 'baz' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Keys` yields `baz`, not the collection of keys. By contrast, `$ht.GetEnumerator().Name` (in PSv3+) works in _both_ editions, but note that using `.Key` instead of `.Name` wouldn't work, and neither would `.Value` to get the collection of _values_, for reasons explained in https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7982

Comment: Thanks, @PetSerAl. I've cleaned up my previous comments and have posted a summary. I see your point about the term _property_, but the average PowerShell user, if I were to guess, conceives of  the `.Keys` in `@{ foo = 'bar'; Keys = 'baz' }.Keys` as property access too, not least because the syntax is the same.